# How to call asmx webservice for collection using BackboneJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, asmx, underscore.js

I hope someone could put me through a code to learn to call asmx webservices from backbone collection. The example i have put here is extremely simple

#### Collection

```
 window["Persons"] = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Person,
        url: "service.asmx/GetPeople"
    });
```

note: I do have a service.asmx file at the point

#### Asmx End point

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            people.Add(new Person(i.ToString()));
        }
        return people;
    }
```

#### The Model

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

when i do the below chrome xhr inspector informs me of this error

```
var family = new Persons();family.fetch();
```

> Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in
>   '/GetPeople'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to override the Backbone.sync() function to customize the persistence and retrieval of models from the server.

You can take a look at the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html#section-11) of how the Backbone.sync() function is overwritten for a local storage alternative.

Comment: so that means i will have to take care of routing if there are more than one Models, Collections on the page right.

Comment: Yep, you will need to take care of the routing yourself